# Mod function in Cocoa (Obj-C) using big numbers

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa, encryption

G'day All,

I showed my Y10 IT class this website:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/plankytronixx/archive/2010/10/23/crypto-primer-understanding-encryption-public-private-key-signatures-and-certificates.aspx

to teach them about public private key encryption.  Initially I asked them to reproduce the calculations themselves in Excel but it turns out that Excel is woefully under gunned when it comes to numbers of that sort.

I decided to demo if for them in both Python and Obj-C.  The entire Python code looks like:

```
from Tkinter import *

def appClose():
sys.exit()

def setup_algorithm():
p = int(pText.get())
q = int(qText.get())
e = int(eText.get())
N = p*q
nText.config(text=str(N))
eText2.config(text=str(e))
modValue = (p-1)*(q-1)
print 'Mod value = ', modValue

result = 0
d = 0
while result != 1:
    d += 1
    if d > 999:
        result = 1
    else:
        result = divmod((e * d),modValue)[1]
dText.config(text=str(d))

def encrypt():
plainTextValue = int(plainIn.get())
N = int(nText.cget("text"))
e = int(eText2.cget("text"))

cipher = pow(plainTextValue, e) % N

cipherOut.insert(0,cipher)

def decrypt():
cipherTextValue = int(cipherIn.get())
N = int(nText.cget("text"))
d = int(dText.cget("text"))

plain = pow(cipherTextValue, d) % N

plainOut.insert(0, plain)


main = Tk()
main.title('Public Private Key Encryption Demo')
main.geometry('700x600+200+100')

pLabel = Label(main, text='p = ')
pLabel.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
qLabel = Label(main, text='q = ')
qLabel.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
eLabel = Label(main, text='e = ')
eLabel.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
pText = Entry(main, width=5)
pText.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10)
qText = Entry(main, width=5)
qText.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10)
eText = Entry(main, width=5)
eText.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10)

space1 = Label(main)
space1.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=50)

pubLabel = Label(main, text='Public key details')
pubLabel.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=10, columnspan=2)
privLabel = Label(main, text='Private key details')
privLabel.grid(row=4, column=4, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=2)

nLabel = Label(main, text='N = ')
nLabel.grid(row=2, column=4)
eLabel2 = Label(main, text='e = ')
eLabel2.grid(row=3, column=4)
nText = Label(main)
nText.grid(row=2, column=5, padx=10)


eText2 = Label(main)
eText2.grid(row=3, column=5, padx=10)

dLabel = Label(main, text='d = ')
dLabel.grid(row=5, column=4)
dText = Label(main)
dText.grid(row=5, column=5, padx=10)

space2 = Label(main)
space2.grid(row=6, column=1, pady=20)

lbPlainIn = Label(main, text='Plaintext In')
lbPlainIn.grid(row=7, column=1)
plainIn = Entry(main)
plainIn.grid(row=7, column=2)
lbCipherOut = Label(main, text='Ciphertext Out')
lbCipherOut.grid(row=9, column=1)
cipherOut = Entry(main)
cipherOut.grid(row=9, column=2)

lbCipherIn = Label(main, text='Ciphertext In')
lbCipherIn.grid(row=7, column=4)
cipherIn = Entry(main)
cipherIn.grid(row=7, column=5)
lbPlainOut = Label(main, text='Plaintext Out')
lbPlainOut.grid(row=9, column=4)
plainOut = Entry(main)
plainOut.grid(row=9, column=5)

space3 = Label(main)
space3.grid(row=10, column=0, pady=20)

pbClose = Button(main, text='Close', command=appClose)
pbClose.grid(row=10, column=3)

pbSetup = Button(main, text='Setup', command=setup_algorithm)
pbSetup.grid(row=4, column=2)

pbEncrypt = Button(main, text='Encrypt', command=encrypt)
pbEncrypt.grid(row=8, column=2, pady=10)

pbDecrypt = Button(main, text='Decrypt', command=decrypt)
pbDecrypt.grid(row=8, column=5, pady=10)
mainloop()
```

My apologies for the huge chunk of code.  I draw your attention to the two methods: encrypt and decrypt.  In this case they work exactly as advertised and can reproduce the calculations shown on the website.

When I wrote the same code in Obj-C:

```
#import "UIController.h"

@implementation UIController

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialize self.
        NSLog(@"Init ran");
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [txtNValue setStringValue:@"187"];
    [txtEValue2 setStringValue:@"7"];
    [txtDValue setStringValue:@"23"];
}

-(int)findDValue:(int)p :(int)q :(int)e
{
    NSLog(@"Find d value");
    int d = 0;
    int result;

    while (d < 1000)
    {
        result = (e * d) % ((p-1)*(q-1));
        if (result == 1) {
            return d;
        }
        d++;
    }

    return d;
}

-(IBAction)setupAlgorithm:(id)sender
{
    int p = [[txtPValue stringValue]intValue];
    int q = [[txtQValue stringValue]intValue];
    int e = [[txtEValue stringValue]intValue];

    int N = p * q;

    [txtNValue setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", N]];
    [txtEValue2 setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", e]];

    int d = [self findDValue:p:q:e];
    NSLog(@"d = %i", d);
    [txtDValue setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", d]];
}

-(IBAction)encrypt:(id)sender
{
    double plainTextValue = [[txtPlainInput stringValue]doubleValue];
    double e = [[txtEValue2 stringValue]doubleValue];
    double N = [[txtNValue stringValue]doubleValue];

    NSLog(@"N = %f and e = %f", N, e);

    double cipher = fmod(pow(plainTextValue, e), N);
    NSLog(@"%f", pow(plainTextValue, e));

    [txtCipherOutput setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", cipher]];

}
-(IBAction)decrypt:(id)sender
{
    double cipherTextValue = [[txtCipherInput stringValue]doubleValue];
    double d = [[txtDValue stringValue]doubleValue];
    double N = [[txtNValue stringValue]doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"N = %f and d = %f", N, d);

    double plain = fmod(pow(cipherTextValue, d), N);
    NSLog(@"%f", pow(cipherTextValue, d));

    [txtPlainOutput setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", plain]];

}

@end
```

The encryption side works and "88" is encrypted as "11" but the reverse does not work.  When decrypting, "11" is decrypted as "149".  The results of the pow() calculation are correct so it must be something to do with the fmod() calculation in Obj-C but I have no idea why.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Thanks,

Comment: BTW, formatting the code to present properly in this post has ruined the indentation.  Sorry.

Comment: An issue with the course as seen in the website: It gives the impression that the message is encrypted with asymmetric encryption but in practice that is not done, a sys metric key is encrypted with the asymmetric encryption. Sure it will work for short messages but that is not the common usage.

Comment: Trace the execution in lldb and watch the values.

Comment: Thanks Zaph.  I have traced it and spat out console outputs on nearly a line for line basis.  It all comes down to: fmod(pow(11, 23), 187) in Obj-C does not produce the same result as pow(11, 23) % 187 in Python and since I didn't have to use a particular data type in python I don't see why Obj-C whould produce a different result.

Comment: It would help if enough code was provided to test. In particular the `@interface` is missing and the the ivars `txtQValue` & `txtEValue` albeit there may just be a typo. Please insure the code you supply will compile. I'm willing to help if I get some code that is complete.

Comment: Any idea how I can get you an entire Xcode project?  There's in excess of 10 files not all of which are "cut and paste"able code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, 11<sup>23</sup> requires too many bits to fit in the mantissa of even a long double.  Fortunately there is a simple algorithm for doing [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) that relies on the fact that

```
(a * b) % m == (a * (b % m)) % m
```

The Wikipedia page has an algorithm on it called the [Right to Left Binary method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method) that works in O(n) time where n is the number of bits in the exponent.  A C version of the function looks like this (NB not compiled or tested).

```
unsigned int 
modular_pow(unsigned int base, unsigned int exponent, unsigned int modulus)
{
    unsigned int result = 1;
    base = base % modulus;
    while (exponent > 0)
    {
        if (exponent % 2 == 1)
        {
           result = (result * base) % modulus;
        }
        exponent /= 2;
        base = (base * base) % modulus;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that many Big Number libraries have a built in version of this function.  For instance, Java's BigInteger has a method called [modPow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow%28java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger%29)

Comment: I take the point, I meant "overflows" in the sense that the number of bits required is too many, not arithmetic overflow.

Comment: Sorry, yes it is too big for a double or a long double, mantissas: 56, 64 respectively.

Comment: @Zaph Reworded it slightly to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you Gents.  I knew I came to the right place.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the Objective-C version does not produce the correct result is because of the precision of the "C" pow() function, even using powl() does not fix the issue, just gets closer:

```
C      pow(11.0, 23.0):  895430243255237361008640  
C      powl(11.0, 23.0): 895430243255237372215296  
Python pow(11, 23):      895430243255237372246531
```

One needs to use "big num" arithmetic, python does that for integers.

Using the Big Int library [JKBigInteger](https://github.com/kirsteins/JKBigInteger)

```
JKBigInteger *cipher = [[JKBigInteger alloc] initWithUnsignedLong:11];
JKBigInteger *N      = [[JKBigInteger alloc] initWithUnsignedLong:187];
unsigned int  d      = 23;

JKBigInteger *pow   = [cipher pow:d];
JKBigInteger *plain = [pow remainder:N];
NSLog(@"plain: %@", plain);
```

NSLog output:

> plain: 88

Comment: Thanks Zaph.  I missed this when you posted it.  Really nice demo.  Ta.